# I am interested in IOS development, Where Do I Start?

Tags: ios

I have a little background in coding, but I'd like to make an iOS app. 
I'm just not sure where to get started or what tools I need. Where do I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I still learn a lot by following tutorials on http://www.raywenderlich.com/, or any other blog/site dedicated to iOS programming.
2. Pick up a book or two, use the book as a reference and practice code for each chapter your read. That's the best way to learn. There are also a lot of videos from the WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/
3. Start working on your own projects. You don't have to master the language in order to begin creating something. Learn as you go.
4. Apple has a lot of documentation in case you're stuck: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
5. Repeat steps 1-4.

Regarding the tools you need:

- a Mac, can't use Windows.
- You need XCode(IDE to develop apps)
- If you want to run your apps on your iphone or ipad you will need to pay for the developer account (~$100 - PER YEAR (thanks Zero)), or you can still join without paying and you get access to documentation and other good stuff. More info at https://developer.apple.com/register/
- You can run the apps in a simulator included with XCode with a free account, but you have to pay to run on device. I don't have a developer account, so I can't offer much info on that -- [UPDATE ON THIS: You can now run your apps in a real device without paying the $99 by using Xcode 7 (in BETA as of now June 2015), I tried running one of my apps and it works =)]